# Using getline() to read in lines from a text file and push_back into a vector of objects

Tags: c++, class, object, vector, getline

I am having issues figuring out how to properly use `getline()` when it comes to classes and objects. I am needing to read in lines of `string` type and then add them to the `myVec` vector using `push_back`. Here is what I have at the moment:

```
vector<myClass> read_file(string filename)
{
    vector<myClass> myVec;
    myClass line;
    ifstream inputFile(filename);
    if (inputFile.is_open())
    {
        while (inputFile.getline(inputFile, line)) // Issue it here.
        {
            myVec.push_back(line);
        }
        inputFile.close();
    }
    else
        throw runtime_error("File Not Found!");

    return myVec;
}
```

Assume the class `myClass` is already implemented.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Assume the class `myClass` is already implemented.

That doesn't help, we can't just assume it's implemented and know what its interface is or how to use it, so we can't answer your question.

Why do you expect `std::ifstream` to know how to work with `myClass`? Why are you passing `inputFile` as an argument to a member function of `inputFile`? Have you looked at any documentation or examples showing how to use `getline`?

Assuming you can construct a `myClass` from a `std::string` this will work (note it reads into a `string` and note you don't need to close the file manually):

```
vector<myClass> read_file(string filename)
{
    ifstream inputFile(filename);
    if (!inputFile.is_open())
        throw runtime_error("File Not Found!");

    vector<myClass> myVec;
    string line;
    while (getline(inputFile, line))
    {
        myClass m(line);
        myVec.push_back(m);
    }

    return myVec;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I realized my mistake shortly after posting. What is the line myClass m(line) for/doing?

Answer (score 2):

Your usage of `getline` doesn't match the signature - you have arguments of wrong type.

```
istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n );
istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n, char delim );
```

If you want to add a `myClass` element to the vector based on the string you read, you have to construct it first and then push it back.