# how to read in data from file to object

Tags: c++, class, object, vector, ifstream

I want to thank any and everyone in advance! What im supposed to do is read data from a file ("inventory.txt") and pass that data along to a vector of objects. All of the data is supposed to be stored in a single vector, including both of the class information, hence the pointer of class dealer in public part of class Vehicle. This is the data in the txt file;

```
2K458D345
Mitsubishi
Eclipse
2003
1,650.00
Rocky Mountain Dealership
Denver, Colorado
```

this is my class definitions:

```
class Dealer{                   //deceleration of class Dealer

private:                        //private variables
string DealerName;
string DealerAddress;

public:                         //public members
                            //class mutators
void setName(string);

void setAddress(string);
                            //class accessors
string getName();

string getAddress();

Dealer();                   // default constructor

Dealer(string, string);        //overloaded constructor
};

class Vehicle{                  //decleration of class vehicle

private:                        //private member variables
string VIN;
string Make;
string Model;
int Year;
double Price;

public:                         // public member variables and functions
Dealer *Dealerprt;          //dealer class pointer

Vehicle();                  //default constructor

Vehicle(string, string, string, int, double);       //overloaded constructor
                            //class mutators
void setVIN(string);                                //sets member variable VIN to value in v

void setMake(string);                               //sets member variable Make to value in m

void setModel(string);                              //sets member variable Model to value in M

void setYear(int);                                  //sets member variable Year to value in y

void setPrice(double);                              //sets member variable Price to value in p
//class accessors
string getVin();                                    //returns value stored in member variable VIN

string getMake();                                   //returns value stored in member variable Make

string getModel();                                  //returns value stored in member variable Model

int getYear();                                      //returns value stored in member variable Year

double getPrice();                                  //returns value stored in member variable Price
```

finally this is the function I have written so far, and carLot is the name of the vector of type Vehicle. Also what i planned to do was create a temporary object to read the data into then pass that to a new object (recommendation of tutor);

```
void readInv(vector<Vehicle>& carLot) {

Vehicle tempVehicle;

ifstream invFile;
invFile.open("inventory.txt");
cout << "the file is being read" << endl;

while( ! invFile.eof()){



}


}
```

I know this is kinda long but im stuck and cant figure out how to properly get the data into the temp object. if there is an easier way im open to it but please i would appreciate any help! thank you so much!

*EDIT* I dident mean vector when i first posted this, what i meant was that i want to read in the data straight from the file into the temp object.

Comment: thats maybe one of the most asked questions on SO. see eg. one of the question listed under related ---->

Comment: Here is a clue: std::getline(invFile, line)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using getline() to read in lines from a text file and push\_back into a vector of objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390500/using-getline-to-read-in-lines-from-a-text-file-and-push-back-into-a-vector-of)

Comment: Just use `invFile >> a` for each of the vegicle class members, declare-initialize an instance and then use `carLot.push_back(obj)` inside the while loop. And please do some research before posting questions

Answer (score 0):

You can use getline() to get one line at a time into a string, then insert into a vector. 
If you have a formated line with different types, I suggest using sscanf. for example:

```
sscanf(line.c_str(), "%f %f", &price, &size);
```

I would take it one step further and upgrade the inventory to a .ini file like so:

```
[david_car]
id = 2K458D345
brand = Mitsubishi
model = Eclipse
year = 2003
price = 1,650.00
dealer = Rocky Mountain Dealership
location = Denver, Colorado
```

create a .ini file reader that will read each line into a map < string, string> with the format: key = value.
after that you will can call each attribute by using:

```
davidVehicle.setModel(map["model"]);
```

you can also apply the sscanf method I mentioned earlier with the map.