# How to make my ifstream "input" look the same in program like it does in file

Tags: c++

I am new to programming, and currently I am learning C++. I am making this kind of project that I learn on, in which there already exists some "premade items", and items that you can create yourself and then be shown. For this, I am currently learning and using `fstream`.

The text in my file looks like this:

[image: Text in file]

But this is how that same text looks in my output:

[image: Text in code]

How can I make it so that the text which I get in the output looks the same as the text in my file?

Here is the part of code responsible for this action:

```
void existingitems(){

    ifstream existingitems("existingitems.txt",ios::in);
    vector<string>exitems;
    string inputs;
    while(existingitems >> inputs){
        exitems.push_back(inputs);
    }
    for(string exisitems : exitems){
        cout<<exisitems;
    }       
}
```

Comment: You want to use `std::getline()` to read line by line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using getline() to read in lines from a text file and push\_back into a vector of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390500/using-getline-to-read-in-lines-from-a-text-file-and-push-back-into-a-vector-of)

Comment: @drescherjm I did what that "fix" in the post you linked to me showed and it did make it so it was separated by spacebar but it still wasn't presented in the new rows but just in a single one. Is it possible to make it so that it is neatly shown in many rows or is it impossible.

Comment: After you have each line in your vector you need to change `cout<<exisitems;` to `cout<<exisitems << '\n';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines of text in the file are delimited by line breaks.  `operator>>` skips leading whitespace before reading data (unless `std::noskipws` is used), and then stops reading when it encounters whitespace.  Spaces, tabs, and line breaks are all considered whitespace by `operator>>`.

So, in your case, you end up reading *individual words* into your `vector` (ie `Primordial`, `Mark`, `-Health`, `300`, etc), not *whole lines* as you are expecting.

When you are then displaying the strings in the `vector`, you are not outputting any delimiters between each string, whether that be spaces or line breaks or whatever.  So everything gets mashed together in one long string.

If you want the output to look *exactly* like the file, use `std::getline()` instead of `operator>>`, and be sure to output a line break after each string:

```
void existingitems(){

    ifstream inputFile("existingitems.txt");
    vector<string> existingitems;
    string input;
    while (getline(inputFile, input)){
        existingitems.push_back(input);
    }
    for(string item : existingitems){
        cout << item << '\n';
    }       
}
```

Comment: Now it works how I imagined it. Thank you very much.